# apache2 mod_proxy working awesome for http://urls and not for https://urls for curl requests

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy, curl

I have proxy setup with apache2 mod_proxy,
Note: I did not change proxy port

```
When I try curl  -x http://proxyurl:80 -L http://destinationservice.com
```

Now it works, but when i try with https://destinationservice.com

```
curl  -x http://proxyurl:80 -L https://destinationservice.com
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 500 from proxy after CONNECT
```

whats the fix for the same.

Comment: silly question but to you have TLS enabled on apache? The server is throwing a 500 error. It looks like its not properly configured for https.

Comment: Yea, I am new to these proxy setups, You mean to say TLS should be enabled on ProxyServer. I guess so.

Comment: Of course, you must configure your server and also provide a certificate.

Comment: Maybe take a look here, I just set up a modern self signed cert recently, but nginx serves it in this example. https://dev.to/codingsafari/securing-a-vps-with-openssl-and-nginx-5cll